# Suddenly getting "No supported authentication methods available" when pushing to github

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I started a github project a few weeks ago. I was able to push changes without any problems (I'm using TortoiseGIT).

Suddenly today when I tried to push my changes, I got "PuTTY Fatal Error" "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods availble" error window.

Anything you can recommend to remedy the problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431314

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out - it happened because I reinstalled TortoiseGIT since starting to work on the project. Pulls went smoothly, but as soon as I tried to push back my changes TortoiseGIT needed my authentication key, which was not configured.

**Edit**

To resolve, I simply cleared all authentication data from my TortoiseGit, under:
Context menu "Tortoise Git" -> Settings -> Saved Data -> Authentication data [Clear]

Comment: how can I get the authentication key?

Comment: @RodrigoAlves - sorry for not noticing your comment until now. It's probably not relevant, but anyway, the key is a file on your disk ... you should always know where it is / back it up. You don't extract it from TortoiseGit. Ask a separate question if somehow this is still relevant.

Comment: For me it started happening after renewing my expired RSA key certificate. None of these steps worked for me, regardless how promising they looked. Still looking for the answer...

Answer (score 150):

For me there was a problem to perform actions against the remote repository only when using TortoiseGit, through **CMD / GitBash** there have been no issue at all.

***So what I did was Very simple:***
I opened **TortoiseGit**-->**Settings** --> **Network** and in SSH Client I changed to "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" instead of "TortoiseGitPlink.exe".

Comment: where is that `ssh.exe` ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe

Comment: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
is where mine was located.

Comment: You saved me twice!) I still love you))

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you installed **TortoiseGit with OpenSSH** and that you use the **SSH authentication method**. If you installed with Putty, there may be a "computer symbol" in the systray called "Putty Pageant".

Comment: You should also make sure the pageant has your key (otherwise, click Add Key and select your keyfile)

Answer (score 16):

**For TortoiseGit Users on Windows**
*(as I originally posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917816/195835))*

I used to setup most of my Github/Bitbucket repositories using the **SSH repository URLs** as (originally) it used to be the only convenient way to prevent TortoiseGit from prompting for your password on every single action.

But setting TortoiseGit up this way was always hair-pullingly painful. Every time it took me *hours* to set up correctly, as the default installation options never seemed to work (even as of 2016, sheesh!).

But TortoiseGit now has better password management for HTTPS, and **[Github actually recommends using HTTPS URLs](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)** wherever possible.

> SSH URL:  `git@github.com:User/repo-name.git`
>
> HTTPS URL: `https://github.com/User/repo-name.git`

The benefits of HTTPS are:

- No managing or generating of SSH keys
- No need to have `pageant.exe` constantly running (which requests your password on each launch)
- Using TortoiseGit from Australia, I find that clones over HTTPS are 5-10x faster than SSH

Comment: Same for gitlab.com (but use gitlab.com in the URL)

Answer (score 13):

In my case, Tortoise Git lost PuttyKey. 
So I had to go to TortoiseGit ***settings > Git > Remote***
and in this section I clicked on ***Remote*** frame my *origin* and PuttyK Key was not set (It was before). I had to set it up again.

Comment: Happened to me after TortoiseGit had updated to latest. This solved it, cheers.

Answer (score 12):

To fix this, I had to manually run Pageant from the start menu:

[image: image description]

Afterwards, I saw pageant in the system tray:

[image: image description]

I could add my key. Normally, keys are in `%userprofile%\.ssh`.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to fix this error by adding the private key into Pageant. I forgot to do this during the key creation, and once I added it I no longer received the error.

Comment: That was the issue with my TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 4):

**[WINDOWS] [Same problem with GIT<sup>(1)</sup> installed after TORTOISE SVN]**

<sup>(1)</sup>not TortoiseGit but the Git development community version.

In git bash :

```
    echo $GIT_SSH
```

was giving

```
    GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
```

(Thanks to Răzvan Flavius Panda and Shahar Hamuzim Rajuan, [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38351660)).

I had to change the value of GIT_SSH in the **Windows system environment variables** from

```
from   C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
to     C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
```

(Before, I tried successfully in git bash to type :

```
    export GIT_SSH='C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe'
```

So we could add this line in C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc for the change to be permanent.
Note that modifying GIT_SSH in C:\Program Files\Git\setup.ini fails)

Answer (score 1):

For me I was getting this error after upgrading GIT to 2.8.0. The issue was due to the $HOME directory being incorrectly read by bash and defaulting to some system location under the windows installation folder: `/c/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile`.

Turns out that a little environment variable cleanup was required. A long while ago I had installed a version of GIT (about 1.7.x) which had created a HOME variable in the system environment variables. This needed to be removed after upgrading to 2.8.0 due to some change in behaviour, rather than adding a further HOME user environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I changed to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` instead of `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` and saved. And changed it back to `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` and it solved this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I unchecked and checked the AutoloadPutty key it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

See my post here. I had this problem just now and tried everything posted here but I couldn't solve it.
At the end was this exact same problem related to an existing PuTTy configuration => [[TortoiseSVN keeps on asking me for my password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225916/tortoisesvn-keeps-on-asking-me-for-my-password/35561015#35561015])

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, which randomly occurred out of the blue after having successfully pushed to my repository over many months.  In my case, in **Tortoisegit->Settings->Git->Remote**, the **Push URL** field was somehow empty.

Answer (score 0):

As a new user I had the same error with GitLab and Eclipse when creating new projects. As a student I use different PCs and had issues with my keys but thought it was resolved as I created a new clean set and my last project is working well. Unfortunately the error occurred again on a new project.

I discovered that creating a new Eclipse project defaulted to my ssh directory rather than the .ssh I am using on my current project. I used the ssh directory initially but after issues changed to .ssh with new keys.

Changing to the .ssh in Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2 fixed the problem.

I am posting this as I have spent a lot of time looking for help with my keys and have not found anything that related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure when cloning that the check box "load putty key" is checked
if not checked it will give the same error

Answer (score 0):

**In TortoiseGit**:

- enter `Settings > Git > Remote`
- remove existing repos and re-add them back.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had to update my version of "msysgit" to a 1.7.10+ version. Once done I did not face the above mentioned error.
I think you might need to check if you have installed [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and if not there install it.