# git cannot push , cannot find Repository

Tags: git, github

I install Git-1.7.9-preview20120201.exe which is the lateest version, and I setup it using the default settings.
  Then i get into the gitbash, and do as the github help pages, everything is ok. Now I created a repo which names Hello-World followed by help pages below:

```
http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/
```

when I do the last step:

```
git push -u origin master
```

error happens:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I [found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758386/git-push-origin-master-error-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods), where this solution was given:

> So to me the following helped: I reinstalled git, and when the wizard asked what ssh client to use, I checked OpenSSH this time!

Now I reinstall git, But I cannot select OpenSSH way when I reinstall git using Git-1.7.9-preview20120201.exe.

Could you please give me some advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the remote settings in your created git repository:

```
% git remote -v
```

and you can fix if it has typo.

```
% git config remote.origin.url git://github.com/YOURNAME/REPONAME.git
```

the configuration is stored in ".git/config". you can rewrite it if need directly.

```
% cat .git/config
```

Comment: hi Usagi, I do as your guide, what should I do next?

Comment: hmm, I thought you had encountered an error because there was a mistake in the remote settings. the problem is likely elsewhere If configured correctly.

can you try connect to the github server use ssh? github server is not allowed shell access, but it can test ssh connection:

    % ssh git@github.com

Comment: and, you'll get the message "Hi YOURNAME! You've successfully authencicated, but GitHub does not provide shel access." from GitHub. If you cannot get the message, you may not have the key pair already configured SSH, there is a mistake.

Comment: see also(setup Git and GitHub on Windows; within SSH key settings): http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/