# Ionic : An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

when i'am try to create an ionic project, i'm got this error message on npm install, anyone know how to fix this, i'm using stable version of node js 3.10.10

```
    ✔ Creating directory .\tabsins - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✔ Downloading - done!
[INFO] Fetching starter template tabs (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tabs/archive/master.tar.gz)
✔ Downloading - done!
✔ Updating package.json with app details - done!
✔ Creating configuration file ionic.config.json - done!
[INFO] Installing dependencies may take several minutes!
> npm install
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

        npm ERR! git clone C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-d75da30c
        C:\Users\AGUNGP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1220-024cd936\git-cache-2cbc3381\31d080cee1d8a4b74e03818aaee14da8062f0ea1:
        Cloning into
        'C:\Users\AGUNGP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1220-024cd936\git-cache-2cbc3381\31d080cee1d8a4b74e03818aaee14da8062f0ea1'...
        npm ERR! git clone C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-d75da30c
        C:\Users\AGUNGP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1220-024cd936\git-cache-2cbc3381\31d080cee1d8a4b74e03818aaee14da8062f0ea1:
        error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
        npm ERR! git clone C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-d75da30c
        C:\Users\AGUNGP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1220-024cd936\git-cache-2cbc3381\31d080cee1d8a4b74e03818aaee14da8062f0ea1:
        fatal: unable to fork
        npm ERR! git clone C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-d75da30c
        C:\Users\AGUNGP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1220-024cd936\git-cache-2cbc3381\31d080cee1d8a4b74e03818aaee14da8062f0ea1:

        npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/resin-io/bonjour.git) fatal: Unable to find remote helper for
        'https'
        npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
        npm WARN addRemoteGit
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit  resin-io/bonjour resetting remote C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef because of error: {
        Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
        npm WARN addRemoteGit
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
        npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
        npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
        npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
        npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
        npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Agung Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror
        git@github.com:resin-io/bonjour.git C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef: Cloning into bare
        repository 'C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef'...
        npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Agung Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror
        git@github.com:resin-io/bonjour.git C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef: error: cannot spawn
        ssh: No such file or directory
        npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Agung Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror
        git@github.com:resin-io/bonjour.git C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef: fatal: unable to
        fork
        npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
        npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
        Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
        npm ERR! node v6.11.0
        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
        npm ERR! code 128

        npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\Agung
        Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:resin-io/bonjour.git
        C:\Users\Agung Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-

    github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef
            npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Agung
            Prabawa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-resin-io-bonjour-git-41f67eef'...
            npm ERR! error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory
            npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
            npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

            npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
            npm ERR!     E:\Project\Mobile\ionic installer\tabsins\npm-debug.log
```

here is the error, i'm try to re-install the node js, but it's the error still showing

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Also, can you make sure the path to your git_ssh doesn't contain any space?

Comment: no, my firewall was disabled, but it's the error still showing, yup i think there're no any space @DevMoutarde

Comment: Please make sure of this though :) I guess you may have read about this topic on SO already : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574267/cannot-spawn-ssh-when-connecting-to-github-but-ssh-t-gitgithub-com-works
Could help !

Comment: after that error, i'm running the npm install manually, and it's work, there nothing to do with the git or ssh, it's just run npm install manually after that error. do you know why this happen ? @DevMoutarde

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood your question mate, could you please reformulate? what do you mean, it has nothing to do with git or ssh?

Comment: Anyway, please reinstall Git (for Windows if you are on a Windows env), add the Git url to your PATH again (make sure C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin; and C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core; are in there). and tell me if it goes better...

Comment: the error still happen, after re-install git, and add Git to windows PATH , and restart the windows @DevMoutarde

Comment: Mhmmm Im afraid I can't help you more :(

Comment: the problem solved by running the ionic start on git bash. i don't know why but it's work @DevMoutarde

Comment: Must be related to git somehow, I read about that yeah but didnt think it would help so I didnt tell ahah, cool you got it working anyway !