# git bash where command giving `Could not find files for the given pattern`

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have installed git bash on my Windows 10,  git command it not working. when I tried `where ssh` command its not giving ssh path.

```
$ where ssh
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

**Git command output**

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=2 git pull
17:10:54.997063 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
17:10:54.999069 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git pull
17:10:55.001073 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
17:10:55.020125 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:10:55.022127 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
17:10:55.025106 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL  
error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I have re-installed git bash twice, How to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cannot spawn ssh" when connecting to Github, but ssh -T git@github.com works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574267/cannot-spawn-ssh-when-connecting-to-github-but-ssh-t-gitgithub-com-works)

Comment: @LéaGris tried those steps. didn't resolve the issue.