# Cannot spawn "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe": Permission denied

Tags: git, windows-10, putty, pageant

Trying to clone a repo using ssh key.
key is loaded using pageant.

when running the git clone command (git clone git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git)
I get this error:

> Cloning into 'core'... error: cannot spawn "C:\Program
> Files\PuTTY\plink.exe": Permission denied error: cannot spawn
> "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe": Permission denied fatal: unable to
> fork

running on windows 10. putty is latest, GIT_SSH points the the right place:

> GIT_SSH="C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"

Running cygwin or cmd as administrator did not resolve this.

Comment: "GIT_SSH points the the right place" Maybe not. This topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574267/cannot-spawn-ssh-when-connecting-to-github-but-ssh-t-gitgithub-com-works suggests that the quotes are wrong — and also that you should be using credential-manager instead.

Comment: you were right - you can post this as an answer. @matt
the " " caused that. the error message is misleading. it's not permission issue, it's just the wrong path.

Comment: It's a duplicate, let's just close the question.

Comment: The important  difference - which made me miss that other question is the error message - it's not "file not found" it's permission denied. I think it's worth keeping, as I didn't see this error when I looked for a solution (the error message is probably new that question is 10 years old).

Comment: Well, feel free to answer it yourself if you insist.