# My git bash doesn't work with github

Tags: github

I successfully installed git bash on my windows 7, and it worked for quite a few days. But in the recent days I'm always getting the same error:

```
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available.
```

Running the command "ssh git@github.com", I get a success message:

```
Hi xxxx, You've successfuly authenticated. but Github does not provide shell access.
```

I checked the .profile, the GIT_SSH is set to the ssh.exe come along with git bash like this:

```
GIT_SSH = "/d/progra~1/git/bin/ssh.exe"
```

However, I noticed that every time I open git bash, there's an error message:

```
sh.exe": GIT_SSH: command not found
```

As a result, I see the TortoisePlink.exe is still in use.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to use https addresses for GitHub repo (`https://github.com/username/yourRepo`), and putting your GitHub credentials in a `%HOME%/_netrc` file: see "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)".

The other alternative would be to check out http://windows.github.com, and see if that setup works.
It will create its own ssh public/private keys and register them on your account.

Note that [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842222/6309) suggests:

```
GIT_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh.exe"
```

(ie a unix-like path)

Comment: GitHub for Windows is simply great!