# Git always asking for my username (and password)?

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)
>   [Automate username/password entry when git pushing over http from windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069256/automate-username-password-entry-when-git-pushing-over-http-from-windows-machine)

I've been using Git on my PC for a while now. One of my new repo's is now asking for a username and password.

before, it just always asked for my password.

here's what i'm going ..

GIT BASH => git push
Username for 'https://github.com':  (I type purekrome then hit enter)
Password for 'https://purekrome@github.com':  yep pew pew secret stuff

then .. wait a long time? 1 minute? 2 mins?

then it commits.

any way I can get it to remember my username? (i don't care about it asking for my password each time).

cheers!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10976222/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094