# remote: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: unable to access

Tags: github

I have the error message:

```sh
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...../...../': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My friend invited me to his repository, and I used his personal token while cloning it.
But it says the above error.

I also tried with my own token but it says the same.

I also faced this when I created my own repository and was making initial commit and push.
This issue has grown ever since Git*Hub has brought token authentication into account.

How can I get past this?

Comment: Does creating a token worked, as mentioned below?

Answer (score 55):

Try and recreate a PAT(Personal Access Token) with, [as scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes), the `repo` ones.
And, for testing, chose an expiration date "`No Expiration`", to be sure it remains valid.
(Note: Since Oct. 2022, you now have [fine-grained personal access tokens](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/), which *must* have expiration date.)
([gdvalderrama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3325322/gdvalderrama) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538793/remote-write-access-to-repository-not-granted-fatal-unable-to-access/70562052?noredirect=1#comment132034355_70562052): The max expiration date is 1 year and has to be manually set)

That token should start with `ghp_...`: it should then authenticate you properly, allowing you to clone the repository, and push back to it.

Note: a token is [akin to a password (but can easily be revoked/regenerated)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/6309), so you should not use any other tokens but your own.

Comment: I tried multiple access tokens and they wouldn't work, then I finally decided to set the main "repo" scope and it finally worked. So thanks.

Comment: Using expiration date "never" is not really possible, last time I did this.

Comment: @SybillePeters True, this is called "No Expiration" now. Only for "classic" token. Fine-grained tokens *must* have expiration date. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The max expiration date is 1 year and has to be manually set

Comment: @gdvalderrama Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 55):

In your Github project, go to `Settings > Actions > General`.
Scroll down to `Workflow permissions`.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually said in the comment how you can edit these permissions.

Comment: Yes, I have also the same question. I tried to find it on github, but did not see this option.

Comment: This is located in Actions -> General. However mine were already set and I still have the error

Comment: select a project goto Settings > Actions > General , can find there "Workflow permissions"

Comment: Omg, this finally solved it for me! Thanks so much 

Comment: It's well for me.

Comment: not working


remote: Write access to repository not granted.

Answer (score 41):

when you create your access token
In expiration: it should say No expiration.
In selecte scopes you mark the repo radio button.
As shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 23):

This is how I solved, step by step

1. Click on your Profile Icon (top-right on Github website)
2. Settings
3. Developer settings (bottom-left)
4. Personal access tokens
5. fine-grained tokens
6. "Generate new token"
7. Write a Token name
8. Pick an expiration date from the menu or a custom one
9. Repository access> All repositories
10. Open "Repository permissions" menu
11. Look for the "Contents" row
12. From the menu at right select "Access> Read and Write"
13. "Generate token" (bottom-left)

Comment: This was the problem for me, I had it working but have edited the token to add a new repo and the permissions were gone.

Comment: thanks for this good answer this only one worked, i not added "Contents" permission.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and appreciation

Answer (score 20):

In my case, I've used **Fine-grained personal access tokens** (**beta** version), with all permissions, but somehow it doesn't work (seems is Github's bug). After changing to the **Personal access tokens (classic)**, 403 disappears.

Comment: This worked for me after lot tries!!

Comment: I've done the same, granted my fine-grained token all permissions possible, and I can't even do a git clone. But after trying further, it seems organisations that I created fail to clone, but direct repositories under my account are cloned successfully.

Comment: @OthmanEmpire have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem, personal repos work but organization repos don't, even though the org is owned by me

Comment: No, I am of the view that this is not possible with the current implementation of fine-grained tokens that Github offers, they are after all still in beta. I've resorted to sticking to classic tokens. Otherwise, the other solution is to create a new dedicated Github account that contains the new organisation, and make that issue the fine-grained tokens. Not too elegant but common solution for other software/products.

Answer (score 14):

Go to your local repository folder and find a hidden folder called ".git". find a file called "config" in the folder as attached below.
[image]

You need to change the url = https://github.com/... to SSH url that can find from GitHub repository(on git hub Web portal) cone menu as below picture.

[image]

This is what the config file looks like, after the change of the url.
[image]

This solved my issue. I belive this will help.

Comment: this did not work for me.

Comment: On Windows, I ended up on this well known issue: [git clone pull continually freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240137/git-clone-pull-continually-freezing-at-store-key-in-cache) (find a solution there)

Comment: this works only if you have an ssh key associated with your github account

Comment: I had SSH key on Github and also on Sourcetree and this worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 12):

Had the same error with a workflow that I've had already used in the past without any problem. Turns out that, in new repositories, workflows only have the *Read* permission. You need to enable the *Read and write* permissions in the repository settings.

Go to *Settings* > *Actions* > *General* > *Workflow permissions* and choose *Read and write permissions*.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As a note, you DO NOT need to enable the "Allow Github Actions to create and approve pull requests" checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

You need to get a write access from for the repo. Try asking your friend to give that. I solved it this way

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need write access just to clone a repository

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve it by setting origin URL with your personal access token

1. Open the terminal
2. 

```
git remote set-url origin https://{your-personal-token}@github.com/{organization}/{repo-name}.git
```

3. 

```
git push
```

Comment: Didn't work with a private repository

Answer (score 4):

For **Fine-grained PAT** After adding these access, I am able to pull and push into my repository.

[image: github permissions]

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of being forced to read the entire (and always HUGE and useless) Microsoft documentation to understand such a simple thing.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to `git clone` a repo **under another organization** (owned by me too) through git bash by input username & **fine-grained personal access tokens** manually.

It took me a while to realize I have to select the **resource owner** to that organization when generating new fine-grained personal access tokens:

[image]

To have commit/push rights, also remember to grant **Contents** read-write permission:

[image]

Comment: Note that this feature has to be enabled for the organization: https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-programmatic-access-to-your-organization/setting-a-personal-access-token-policy-for-your-organization

Answer (score 1):

I gave below permissions on the GitHub and it worked.

[image: Permissions]

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Click "Generate new token"
3. Input token description e.g. "Sourcetree Mac Token", select "repo" checkbox, and click "Generate token"
4. Copy the generated token
5. Add your GitHub account to Sourcetree, but now rather than using OAuth, select Basic authentication
6. Input your username
7. Paste the generated token as password, Generate Key, and Save

[image: Generate Key]

Comment: worked for me on Mac M1!!

Answer (score 1):

I Used Classic Token and pasted it in the password area in terminal. It Worked. If Your fine grain Tokens fails to work then try classic token and select the repo radio area like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/71138077/17359554

Comment: This is what I did and worked

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the error message is misleading. I've seen this message appear when I forgot to add "Contents/read" access to the  fine-grained personal access token. After adding the "read-only" permission, I was able to successfully clone the repository, even when the token has no write access.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who gets here in the future, after trying a few of the above solution and things still dont work. When creating a PAT:

1. `Repository access` -> `Only select repositories` -> Give access to **both** main repo and submodule repo.
2. `Permissions` -> `Repository permissions` -> Give `Read-only` access to `Contents` and `Metadata`.

[image: expected permissions]

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved on generating a Token(classic) with below options

- no expiry
- selected "repo" scope

Answer (score 0):

Your friend as generate a Fine-grained personal access tokens and make sure you gives you permissions to the repo and user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess this means that the owner of the repository has to provide a fine-grained token to any collaborators but when using a classic token, that is not needed, it works just with `repo` scope selected.

Answer (score 0):

When you create (Personal access tokens) select under Permissions -> Repository ->permissions
(select all read-write fields where possible) , do the same for (Account permissions
) then you will have all access and such an error should not occur. At least in my case, it helped, since all the answers in this article did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a fine-grained "personal access token" with correct code writing permissions: https://github.com/settings/tokens?type=beta
2. Adjust the remote url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://{username}@github.com/{username}/{repo-name}.git
```

3. Use the personal token as password

Comment: it won't work I am sure.... when you're invited to a repo, what would you do?

Comment: Did not read the "invite" part, I guess. This was working for the owner.

Answer (score 0):

My GitHub Actions configuration contains instructions for fetching code with the custom bot's SSH key:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    ssh-key: ${{ secrets.BOT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    submodules: true
```

The same key will probably be used for pushing the code. Hence you have to give the write access to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

the one that worked for me

Caching your GitHub credentials in Git

GitHub Docs
https://docs.github.com › getting-started-with-git › cachi...

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening for a repository that is part of an organization:

Select your organization > `View organization` > `Settings` > Select `Member Privileges` on the left panel, under the `Access` category > Update the `Base permissions` to `Write`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitHub CLI by running gh auth login which will let you setup your credentials using your token instead of your old password.