# How to push to organisation's repo on github

Tags: git, github

I was invited to join an organization on GitHub as a member. It has an empty repo, to which I wanna push my local code. I'm getting the following error.

remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyy.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Are you sure you accepted the invitation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have accepted the invitation, double-check the [token used](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Make sure it is *not* a [fine-grained one](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token), but a classic one, with [scope `repo`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes), as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562052/6309).