# Git Not Allowing to push changes to remote Repo

Tags: github, git-push

I have been facing the following error everytime I try to push changes to a remote repository:

"ERROR: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. "

I have the SSH keys already set I am able also to git pull and git clone with no problems, the issue is just when I try to push changes.

Do you have any idea about ow to solve it ??
I am using a MacOs .

Thank you in advance for your time.

I removed the SSH keys from github account also I generated them again on my machine and added them again in my github account, but no luck so far.

Comment: GitHub's permission checks are done by GitHub (not by Git, which has no permissions stuff in it at all). GitHub have a whole complicated set of access controls described on the GitHub help pages. Use those to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Is it a token issue as I mentioned [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562052/6309)?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with the admin of the repo, there was a weird behavior, but he added me again as a team member and it worked, thank you, everyone, for the support.