# git server's host key is not cached in the registry

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I try to pull changes from my local repo to a remote repo. When I type

```
git pull origin hubert
```

I get the following error:

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You 
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But When I type

```
ssh hubert@remove_host
```

It work fine.

I'm use `Windows 7 32 bits` and I have the same files in the dir:

- C:\Users\hubert\.ssh
- C:\Users\hubert\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Git\.ssh

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value (in a git-bash session) of `$GIT_SSH`: if it involves `plink.exe`, it won't use `$HOME/.ssh/known_host` (which already include origin server, since a manual ssh works)

You can either configure plink:

```
plink.exe hubert@remote_host
# answer 'y'
```

Or you can set [git to use openssh](https://superuser.com/a/748190/141).

Comment: Please, I got this error: `FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
 sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`

Comment: @hubert What GIT_SSH referred to?

Comment: It refer to `C:\Program Files\putty\plink.exe`

Comment: @hubert Exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17713917/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/6309 should help.

Comment: I simply change my GIT_SSH value to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`