# TortoiseSVN keeps on asking me for my password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have source code checked out on my Linux machine. I connect to it via [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)). On a Linux machine, the `SVNROOT` is set to <mylogin>@<serverhost>. In additon, `SVN_SSH` is set to point to my private key that the system administrator generated for me. On Linux, I am NEVER prompted for the password. The system administrator claims that the private key takes care of it.

On the *same* directory that I access through Samba, I run TortoiseSVN. However, it constantly prompts me to enter a password for <mylogin>. My system administrator says that I have no password, just the private key.

What do I do with TortoiseSVN so that it does not prompt me for the password?

Comment: Working copies are **not** meant to be shared.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has a good chapter regarding SVN and SSH in its "help" documentation. The basic point is that you use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect.

So you need to configure PuTTY correctly first.

Comment: Could you add a link or document _how_ you use PuTTY to connect?

Comment: Agree with @Jon-Eric, this answer is pretty useless without reference to how.

Comment: There is a [Docs](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/docs.html) Link on the website I mentioned.

Answer (score 30):

Tortoise SVN 
right click on desktop -> Tortoise SVN-> settings -> saved data -> authentication data (button press 'clear') !
try logging in now again !

Comment: this didn't work for me. I still have to enter username and password each time I try to do a svn update.

Comment: Works for me. Once cleared, password entered. Close and re-open without require password! Thanks!

Comment: The "Clear" button next to "Authentication Data" is disabled for me. Why would this be? No matter how many times i enter the credentials, its keeps again. Please help.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem as mentioned by @ShabinMuhammed please help..

Answer (score 17):

**If you don't have a password, but have a key (.ppk):**

Download PuTTY and run it. Interesting keys are:

- *Session – Host name and port*,
- *Connection – Data – Auto-login username*,
- *Connection – SSH – Auth – Private key for authentication*.

Now save your configuration — go back to *Session* and enter e.g. `MyServer` into *Saved sessions* text field, then click *Save*. After that UX nightmare you can re-open PuTTY, double-click on your `MyServer` in session list and be logged in without providing anything.

TortoiseSVN connection string should look like `svn+ssh://MyServer/path/to/repo`. Long story short, `MyServer` string is checked by TortoiseSVN in PuTTY settings.

---

**If you don't have a key, but have a password:**

Go to TortoiseSVN – Settings – Network – SSH Client, and set it like that:
 `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -l <username> -pw <password>`

Your connection string should look as usual: `svn+ssh://serverhostname/path/to/repo`, without `username@`.

This is insecure and all, for those who don't give a f-ck and want it now.

Answer (score 14):

By selecting "Settings" from the TortoiseSVN menu, and clicking the "Network" section, you can configure the "SSH client" command line. Adding " -i " followed by the path to your private key there will make the authentication work as it does on Linux.

The default SSH client is a program called "TortoisePlink", which uses a different key file format than the OpenSSH client that's used on Linux. You can convert the key supplied by your sysadmin to that format using the puttygen tool available here http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Alternatively, you could use an OpenSSH client with TortoiseSVN. The ssh.exe that comes with cygwin works fine, for example.

Comment: +1/2 for "configure the "SSH client"" (well, OK +1) Here's how: Tortoise SVN-> settings -> Network. In the SSH GroupBox click [Browse]; navigate to "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" then add -i "path\to\private.ppk"

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a key to connect via SSH, and that key is password protected, it isn't SVN asking you for your password, it is SSH (or Plink).

SVN will make multiple calls, each establishing its own connection, and SVN doesn't know anything about the password requirement of SSH, thus it cannot cache the password.

You can avoid this by using an SSH key agent. For example, if you're using PuTTY, then use PuTTY's, Pageant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing what can be happening since I had a similar situation.

It seems that **PuTTY will use a configuration matching the domain of the svn host you are trying to connect to from Tortoise SVN if it exists**.

So if your svn host is located at *myServer.de* and you have a configuration in PuTTY named *myServer.de* that doesn't match the connection criteria of your SVN server and then you try to access from Tortoise SVN to *svn+ssh://myUser@myServer.de/blablabla* PuTTY (it is used by default to establish the SSH connection to the server) will use the configuration *myServer.de* instead of the one supplied by Tortoise SVN.

It happened to me and it was driving me crazy! In my case it was asking for the password since the supplied key in PuTTY's configuration was outdated!!!

I hope it helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

If your path to repo is like `svn+ssh://server@hostname/path/...` and you have password to access it, you can solve it in network settings like this:

Settings -> Network -> SSH client

`C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -pw [password]`

[image: TortoiseSVN SSH Network Settings]

Answer (score 1):

This happen when you connect to svn+ssh using a key (private key) that got a passphrase. In this case Tortoise svn will use ssh (like mine is putty) and it will prompt you for password.

To allow it to not asking you for passphrase **you need to use Pageant, after you add key to Pageant, it will keep the phrase and not ask you more...**

To know how to add key, read the below:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pageant-to-streamline-ssh-key-authentication-with-putty

Comment: THIS is the easiest way to do it!  Install Putty, run Pagent, rt click it in the tray, add your private key.  Enter password for private key.  Tortoise then silently uses the key and no more password frustration.

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot clear TortoiseSVN authentication data, as the ["clear" button is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfTuR.png):

Simply edit the SSH client that TortoiseSVN is using by:
`On Desktop, right click -> TortoiSVN -> Settings -> Network -> SSH client`,
then add your username and password to the path, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoswf.png):

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -l [username] -pw [password]
```

Also, make sure you apply the above to any third-party software or IDE that uses TortoiseSVN, in my case I use Intellij IDEA on Windows: `(CTRL+ALT+S) Open Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> SSH -> SSH executable`, add your username and password to the path, add your username to `User name`, and choose `Password` as your authentication method, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nScvQ.png).

Answer (score 0):

In Git, create a Personnel Access Token (PAT) with all access rights and when the Authentication screen pops up, use the PAT as password.