# Eclipse keeps asking for svn password

Tags: eclipse, svn

Whenever I'm trying to synchronize/update my projects with SVN repo it asks me for password. It drives me nuts, I'm checking "save password" checkbox and it doesn't work at all.. what is more, I cant use a simple password.

It might be somehow connected with my company's proxy but eclipse plugin update sites work just fine.

I have a Subversion directory in my AppData dir, maybe I should delete this?
I can also provide additional info, I just don't know what may be relevant.

I'm using `Subclipse` with `JavaHL` provider and my `Eclipse` version is 4.4.2 but I have the same problem on `Eclipse` 3.7.2

Comment: Have you tried to switch to SVNKit? See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703377/which-subversive-connector-discovery-to-use/7703748#7703748 for some details / differences to the 2 connectors. Add some information what Subversion clients you have installed additionally (including version).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This one worked well : http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/ide/eclipse/fix-eclipse-svn-always-asking-for-login-and-password-clear-keyring-or-cache

There is some files to delete :

- Delete (or rename .old) in Eclipse : /configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.keyring
- Remove the file in your profile (AppData/Roaming or ~) : /.subversion/auth/svn.simple

Go to SVN perspective and enter login/password. Should keep it now.

Comment: THanks, this worked for me : Remove the file in your profile (AppData/Roaming or ~) : /.subversion/auth/svn.simple

Answer (score 18):

Here's what worked for me. I went to Window/Preferences/Team and saw that there were two "SVN" sub-menus. I'm not sure how I got to this state, but I may have installed both Subversion and Subclipse at some point.

Anyway, in the first SVN submenu, there is a tab for SVN Connector. And in the other SVN menu, there is a subsection labelled "SVN interface". Both of these provide a drop-down list to select a connector/interface. In my case, in the first SVN menu, the SVN Connector was set to "SVNKit". In the second SVN menu, it was set to "JavaHL".  I changed this to SVNKit, and have had no problems since.

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was going to Window->Preferences->Team then under 'SVN Interface' select the 'SVNKit (Pure Java)' option.

Answer (score 10):

None of the current answers worked for me in eclipse neon. Therefore I edited hash file in /.subversion/auth/svn.simple/[filename]
I added password informarion:

```
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 51
<https://svn.example.com:443> Subversion Repository
K 8
username
V [length_of_username]
[username[
K 8 
password
V [length_of_password]
[password]
END
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too on Eclipse Photon!

Comment: Thanks. Worked on Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) / Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

This is what has just worded for me (Mars, subclipse, SVNKit):
I read the $WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log file, and found this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2015-09-04 09:24:33.282^M
!MESSAGE Authorization infrastructure (org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth) not installed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth.AuthorizationDatabase cannot be found by org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723
```

Duckduckgoed the package name **org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth** and found it in [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.core/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth/3.2.200.v20100517), where I downloaded the jar file, which I copied into my $ECLIPSE_HOME/dropins directory.
After restarting eclipse there was no error in the log, I was just asked once my master password. No more annoying password dialogs since then.

Comment: This worked for me with a similar problem with Perforce.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide one more solution that works for me after trying another solutions.

It was as easy as changing the combo "Apply To" in the login-pass pop-up window from "http://..." to "Repository Location".

I deleted C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth too as commented.

Eclipse version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. went to Window/Preferences/Team/SVN
2. set to "SVNKit" from "JavaHL".

I changed this to SVNKit, and have had no problems since.

Answer (score 1):

There are high chances that Eclipse (at least mine does: Eclipse 4.8.0 with Subclipse and SVNKit 1.8.12) is using the password storage of the command line Subversion utilities which are stored (at least under Linux) under `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple`.
As Daniel Juniszek pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637119/771461) you could edit this by hand, but doing this from command line is a little bit simpler:

Do an `svn up` in the project folder, give your password if it asks for, and enter yes for the `Store password unencrypted (yes/no)?` question.
After it finished updating successfully, do an `svn up` again to check that it does not ask for your password again.

If it asks again then maybe you have the same problem as me:
**I had wrong permissions set** on two hash files in the above directory (it was **r--r--r--** instead of **rw-r--r--**) so the subversion command was unable to update the file. After I changed the permission with a `chmod u+w ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/YOUR_FILENAME_HERE` command, the `svn up` updated the file with the password and finally Eclipse stopped asking me for password as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you (xwhyz) provided the answer yourself: delete the files in this folder:
`c:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\`
(Eclipse Neon.2 with Subclipse 1.10.13 + Subversion Client Adapter 1.10.3)

**Edit:** I also disable Eclipse's automatic check for updates, and is now doing that manually. When prompted for the SVN password just press `OK` 3-5 times, without re-typing the password.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried all methods you proposed and it didn't work. 
Solution for me was:

1. Right click on TortoiseSVN
2. Settings
3. Network
4. Subversion server file, button 'Edit'
5. I added:

   [groups]
   group_name = group_address

   [group_name]
   http-proxy-exceptions = proxy_exceptions

   http-proxy-host = proxy_host

   http-proxy-port = port_number

   store-passwords = **yes**

where I filled group_name, group_address, proxy_exceptions, proxy_host, port_number and checked 'yes'.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: You've answered the wrong question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225916/tortoisesvn-keeps-on-asking-me-for-my-password

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution to try, and worked for us, was to reset the user's password on their SVN account.  We recently upgraded to a newer version of CollabNet SVN and we didn't migrate the user accounts (if that's something we could have done, it might have been nice).

There were two developers encountering this issue: one user forgot their password and the account had not yet been created for the other user.  It would've been nice to see a more descriptive error message about the credentials in the behavior from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem and below solution worked for me: Open Windows - preferences - Team - SVN and check for SVN interface, it should be client as SVNKit in place of JavaHL and restart eclipse / RAD ad it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Change setting in eclipse**
Step 1: Open eclipse then windows ->preferences
[image]

Step 2: Click on Team -> SVN -> inside SVN Interface , select client as -> SVNKit(Pure Java)V... -> Apply
[image]